# Dart's private members being exposed

Tags: object, dart, private

I am not sure if something is wrong, or if I've missed out something VERY FUNDAMENTAL.
But I AM able to access private constructors, methods, and members of a class outside the class.

```
class A {
  static final _a = 1;
}

void main() {
  print(A._a);
}
```

**Output**:

```
1
```

**Dart version:**

```
Dart VM version: 2.8.4 (stable) (Unknown timestamp) on "linux_x64"
```

Screenshot of the test:
[image: Screenshot of the test]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> identifiers that start with an underscore (_) are visible only inside the library. Every Dart app is a library, even if it doesn’t use a library directive.

Private means that it's available in the file it's written in and not accessible to other files. So it's not a true private. You can read more about it [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility).